# Set the default timezone in symfony

Tags: php, date, symfony1, doctrine, timezone

i want to know how can i set timezone for an entire project?

i'm using symfony 1.4 with doctrine and i have a problem with datetime saving.
whenever i save a record, it's time is not correct and i know that's because of timezone.

i know i can use `date_default_timezone_set()` function to set default timezone, but i have to do it in every single action that i'm using date and it's not right.

is there an easier way to do it? i think doctrine should have something to set it automatically but i don't know how.

Comment: Somehow my Sf2 application isn't using the right timezone and daylight saving time, but I can't find a parameter similar to `default_timezone` in the Sf2 config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symfony way is to use `default_timezone` in *settings.yml*. See [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_default_timezone) for more details.

Comment: yeah. that's way better. i was looking for something exactly like this.thanks

Comment: Why down vote? You should at least write a reason if you believe this is not the right way.

Answer (score 3):

For one, you may consider setting it in your `php.ini`. If you're on a shared server, that's not a viable option, but the common place to set project-global properties is the `config/ProjectConfiguration.php`, just after plugin setup.