# Symfony2 Date.TimeZone() Issue

Tags: php, mysql, date, symfony, datetime

I have tried everything under the sun to enable the ability to run this command after installing Symfony2.

> php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup OR php app/console cache:clear

I get this error every time:

> [ErrorException] Warning: date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/rt/vendor/jms/serializer-bundle/JMS/SerializerBundle/DependencyInjection Configuration.php line 66

On line 66:

> ->scalarNode('default_timezone')->defaultValue(**date_default_timezone_get**())->end()

I've tried this Stack Post:

> [Warning: date_default_timezone_get():](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162437/warning-date-default-timezone-get)

I've tried to edit ALL php.ini files, phpinfo() for XAMPP shows:

> date/time support                   enabled
>   "Olson" Timezone Database Version   2013.4
>   Timezone Database                   internal
>   Default timezone                    UTC

$ php --ini shows

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc (I edited this one as well)

php.ini shows

> date.timezone = UTC

I cannot run php composer.phar install without the ability to get past this stupid date_default_timezone_set() error.

Please help, its been 2 haggling days trying to get this fixed and I am at my wits end.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set the default timezone in symfony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777191/set-the-default-timezone-in-symfony)

Comment: no that is not the issue. I have only one php.ini file plus that post suggests editing the settings.yml file which was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue adding this code to the `app/AppKernel.php` file:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel {

    public function init() {
        // Change timezone
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');

        parent::init();
    }

    // ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good option is also to add the following into the virtualhost file (if applicable)

`php_value date.timezone America/Caracas`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below in your virtualhost file as suggested above

```
php_value date.timezone America/Caracas
```

You can also have the same in the .htaccess file in the web folder of your symfony2 instead.

Check the php.ini under both

```
/etc/php5/apache2/ ( for apache2 )
```

and

```
/etc/php5/cli/     ( for command line )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default timezone to your php.ini 
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file
Don't forget to restart the server