# default_timezone is overrided by application

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

I'm going mad because I spent the 3 last hours trying to modify `Datetime` on Symfony2 because `new Datetime()` return me an object with the time on the UTC format although a sample php file return me the Datetime on `Europe/Paris` format.

The TZ is set on all `php.ini` but still overrided by `Symfony2`.

> Symfony 2.4.4 on PHP 5.5.12-1~dotdeb.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran with this same issue, I solved doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23353707/453348)

Comment: All solutions in your thread didn't solved the problem. ( virtual host / AppKernel modifications ).
Something is modifying my TZ beetween the AppKernel and my Controller action...

Comment: Fixed it with a savage solution : i added `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');` at the end of my Listener including IPBWI.